# How to create multiple UIViews Inside the UIPageviewController using iOS storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I am trying to create different `views` Inside the `pageviewcontroller` but the `pageviewcontroller` want to show top of the half on `viewcontroller`. Please check below `Image`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJbUn.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a screenshot of your storyboard or a code snippet demonstrating how you're adding that view.

Comment: sure. give me few hours! @Islam

Comment: Are you using storyboard or programmatically?  If you are using storyboard make sure to check the dimensions of the `UIView` because sometimes they can go to 0,0,0,0 after editing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scene for your CustomPageViewController (inherited from UIPageViewController) in the storyboard and add to viewDidLoad of this class:

```
self.dataSource = self;
self.delegate = self;
```

Now you can provide custom view controllers via UIPageViewControllerDataSource methods:

```
- (nullable UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
- (nullable UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

You can also create your custom view controller' scene in the storyboard and load it in the code:

```
CustomViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomViewController"];
```